# Lightning Design in inline visualforce page

Tags: lightning-design-system, inline-visualforce

I'm trying to render an Apex:outoutpanel with some Text based on certain criteria within an Inline VF page. I will be adding Lightning Design within this panel. But looks like it doesn't properly showing up. Here's my code:

```
<apex:form id="map_Form">

    <!--Displays the Map-->
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="false">
            <div style="width: 100%;" id="mapDiv">
                    <div id="map" style="width: 60%; height: 600px; float: left;margin:0px;color:black;"></div>
                    <div id="panel" style="width: 40%; float: left;margin:0px;"></div>
                </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
        <!--End of the Map-->

        <!--Displays Validation message-->
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="true">
                <div class="slds-text-color--error">Error shows here!</div>
        </apex:outputPanel>  
        <!--End of the validation message--> 

</apex:form>
```

This 'Error shows here!' is still a plain text. Any thoughts??

Comment: Have you added the SLDS CSS in your Static Resource and included it your page? Also, include all your components within a div with your scoping class. You have to do that, otherwise the slds classes won't be recognized. [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lightning_design_system) may help.

Comment: @N.B. There's no need to use the static resource. There's a new [`apex:slds`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm) that provides your page with the latest SLDS automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualforce pages are served up in an iframe, and so do not inherit Lightning's CSS by default. You need to manually import SLDS if you intend to use it:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:slds />
<div class="slds-scope">
    <!-- your page here -->
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible for Visualforce pages within Lightning Experience to be automatically styled with Lightning Design System.

[Automatically Style Existing Visualforce Pages with Lightning Experience Stylesheets (Beta)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_vf_lightningstylesheets.htm)

It takes your standard Visualforce components and re-styles them when viewed within Lightning Experience. This may be useful in scenarios such as these.